# Sharing Memcached between Jetty Instances

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, jetty, guice

I'm writing integration tests against a Google App Engine project that is running on a local Jetty instance.

Before running my tests, I spawn a new instance of my GAE web service at `http://localhost:8083`. On startup, the web service creates a memcached instance that it will write data to. We're using Google Guice, so this is done with a binding that looks like this:

```
bind(AsyncMemcacheService.class).toInstance(MemcacheServiceFactory.getAsyncMemcacheService());
bind(MemcacheService.class).toInstance(MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService());
```

Once the web service is up and running, I start my integration tests. Crucially, they are started on a separate Jetty instance that creates its own memcached bindings.

I've written an integration test that looks like the following:

```
@Test(groups = "integration")
private void doSomeTest() {
    //set up some precondition for the test
    String id = "myIntegerObject";
    this.memcached.putSomeObject(id, 0);

    try {
        //call an endpoint that relies on the previously set value
        String url = "http://localhost:8083/api/increment/" + id;
        this.http.post(url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Assert.fail("Test failed. See inner exception for details.", e);
    }

    //verify that hitting the url had the desired effect
    Assert.assertEquals(this.memcached.getSomeObject(id), 1);
}
```

This test always fails on the `Assert.assertEquals(...);` line, because my web service and my integration test are writing to different instances of memcached.

Is there a way to set up a system-wide memcached instance that my web service, unit tests, and integration tests all share?

Answer (score 3):

Would the [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi) work for you here? While it's intended to allow you to connect to your production `appspot.com` app, you can also use it to connect to the local dev_appserver:

```
new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8083).credentials("test@example.com", "");
```

Any API calls you make will use the remote API to access the other instance. Note, the Remote API is not restricted to the datastore API as the docs suggests. Memcache works in the same way.

I created an [example Eclipse project](https://code.google.com/p/sauer/source/checkout?repo=java-remote-api) which is both a 'hello world' App Engine app, which you can deploy or run locally, and a trivial `TestClient.java`, which use the remote API to perform remote memcache `get()` and `put()` calls:

```
$ java client.TestClient localhost 8083 test@example.com pass foo bar

new RemoteApiOptions()
.server("localhost", 8083)
.credentials("test@example.com", "pass")
mc.get("foo") -> null
mc.put("foo", "bar")
mc.get("foo") -> bar
```

Comment: That would do exactly what we want. This is an awesome idea! Thanks Fred!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as advertised. When I run this code with the line `RemoteApiOptions options = new RemoteApiOptions().server("localhost", 8083).credentials("", "");`, I get a java.io.IOException: `can't get appId from remote api; status code = 404`.

Comment: Changing the `localhost` argument to `http://localhost` fixes the 404 problem, but now fails with a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException `email not set`. Adding a fake email address and password to the `.credentials()` function yields a com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.LoginException: `Login failed. Reason: BadAuthentication`. Is there a default account that we should be using here?

Comment: This functionality appears to be documented at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi, but they don't make any mention of what credentials to use when connecting to a memcached instance on localhost.

Comment: The `can't get appId from remote api; status code = 404` error message indicates that the app you're connecting to is missing the `com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet` servlet-mapping for the `/remote_api` endpoint in its `web.xml`. See [the Remote API docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi).

Comment: The hostname must equal `localhost`, which is recognized as a special value, so that the Remote API will use the `dev_appserver_login` cookie to authenticate itself. When using local host you can specify any email address for the `credentials()` `username` argument. The `password` argument is unused and can be left blank.

Comment: When connecting to a production app (`*.appspot.com` or `your.customdomain.com`), you'll need a valid Google Account username and password. If your Google account uses [two step verification](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744) you'll need to use an [application specific password](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833).